# Realm: Bundling a Realm with an App

Tags: swift, swift2, realm

I want to ship my app with several databases.

1) I have a random generated ".csv" file converted with Realm Browser to "default.realm".

2) I put it in /project_name/project_name/Resources and drop it inside Xcode to project files.

3) I checked "Copy bundle resources"[image]

4)Created

```
import RealmSwift

class CarItem: Object {
    dynamic var id = String()
    dynamic var first_name = String()
}
```

In ViewDidLoad wanted to return results from file

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

   let conf = Realm.Configuration(
        fileURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("default", withExtension: "realm"),
        readOnly: true)

   let realm = try! Realm(configuration: conf)
   let results = realm.objects(Item.self)
   print(results)
}
```

5) But results are empty (database have 1000 rows all filled with data).... what am i down wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CarItem.self` replace `Item.self` ?

- Open `default.realm` by `Realm Browser`(Your can download it from App Store).

  [Open .realm file by Realm Browser screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOGsY.png)
- Check `Class Name` and `Class Members`.
- [Example](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/swift-2.2/Migration/AppDelegate.swift)

Comment: Why is that in app delegate? Should a move my methods from ViewDidLoad to app delegate then?

Comment: btw... the error was in wrong Class.Object name, change it to "MOCK_DATA".. same as generated data from internet.